# Неправильный синтаксис определения ограничения TABLE

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

При выполнении следующего скрипта:

```
USE [Bookshop]
GO

create table [Users](
    [UserID] [int]  primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Login] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL unique,
    [Password] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Adress] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Telephone] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL, default '+380',
    [Role] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    )
    GO
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Сообщение 142, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 2
Неправильный синтаксис определения ограничения "TABLE".
```

В чем она заключается?

Comment: Вы определитесь у вас [tag:mysql] или [tag:sql-server]. Ошибка из-за `,` после `[Role] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL`.

Comment: Нет, не из-за этого. Ранее создавал другую таблицу и там присутствует запятая в конце последнего поля, да и убрать попробовал, также не помогло...

Comment: 2 лишние запятые - первую указали, вторая в определении поля Telephone. И уберите квадратные скобки у типов полей.

Comment: @Akina в SQL Server квадратные скобки у типов допустимы.

Comment: @vikolyada Ссылочкой на документацию поделитесь, пожалуйста...

Comment: @Akina похоже это недокументированная фича. Ничего в документации не нашел, но [вот](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5721/how-to-turn-off-delimiters-in-generated-sql-scripts-for-data-types-in-sql-server) человек жалуется на квадратные скобки при генерации скрипта создания таблицы.

Comment: @Akina, вот, например: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.105).aspx
"An identifier that complies with all the rules for the format of identifiers can be used with or without delimiters. An identifier that does not comply with the rules for the format of regular identifiers must always be delimited."

Comment: @minamoto Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно убрать из скобок типы и убрать запятую перед default и в конце. В скобки помещают только названия, если они совпадают с ключевыми словами SQL.

```
    USE [Bookshop]
    GO

create table [Users](
    [UserID] int  primary key IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Login] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL unique,
    [Password] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Adress] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Telephone] nvarchar(15) NOT NULL default '+380',
    [Role] nvarchar(5) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Тут прочитал коментарий, скобки все-таки можно оставить, проблема в запятых.